# Sync Audio & Video From Pi Camera & USB Microphone

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to stream low-quality audio & video from my Raspberry Pi to another device. I have a Raspberry Pi camera & a USB microphone. Both devices work separately but i cannot seem to get the audio & video to sync up.

I am running Raspbian. I began by compiling ffmpeg as described at http://blog.giuseppeurso.net/raspberry-pi-streaming-webcam/.

Here is my ffmpeg info:

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 27 2014 00:14:25 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-filter=movie --enable-filter=aresample --enable-avfilter
```

Before i get streaming working, i want to just dump the audio & video to an MKV file. I wrote this script to dump audio & video to out.mkv until terminated.

```
#!/bin/bash

vpipe=/tmp/videopipe
apipe=/tmp/audiopipe
vw=320
vh=240
fps=15

trap "rm -r $vpipe" EXIT
trap "rm -r $apipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $vpipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $vpipe
fi

if [[ ! -p $apipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $apipe
fi

raspivid -t 0 -w $vw -h $vh -fps $fps -o - > $vpipe &
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 > $apipe &

ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -fflags nobuffer \
    -r $fps \
    -i $vpipe \
    -fflags nobuffer \
    -analyzeduration 0 \
    -i $apipe \
    -map 0:0 \
    -map 1:0 \
    -filter:a aresample=async=1 \
    -c:a copy \
    -c:v copy \
    out.mkv
```

The audio & video are grossly out of sync. I have tried changing the framerates on both raspivid & ffmpeg with no success. Not sure what piece of the puzzle i am missing.

Comment: @goldilocks: This is completely a RPi issue! The problem is the camera board oscillator doesn't do 25 Hz, rather [does 24.8 Hz or so](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=98541&p=683936), which results in a surplus of frames. Using `-r 25.375` for video input (before `-i $vpipe`) and `-r 25` for final output (after `-c:v copy`) worked for me.

Comment: @K3---rnc Good to know.  I've reopened this so you can provide an answer.  Hopefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the raspberry pi camera module does not, in fact, produce 25 frames per second. Instead, the frequency determined by the oscillator within is more like 24.8 Hz, which, at increasing video length, produces unexpected surplus of frames.

The [current solution](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=98541&p=683936) is to consider the frame rate of video input as 25.375 FPS (or roughly so), so the ffmpeg command becomes:

```
ffmpeg [...] -r 25.375 -i $vpipe [...] -r 25 -i $apipe [...] -r 25 out.mkv
```

Note it is perhaps wiser to have all the processes in a single pipe (`raspivid | ffmpeg`) and ffmpeg read ALSA as well (`-f alsa -i hw:1,0`).

Comment: This has been "fixed" (the drift is about 100 times lower now, below 0.01%) on the newest firmware. The initial sync is still a problem. [ I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer ]

Comment: Did you get this working successfully? I am looking at using my pi-cam and a usb mic and streaming them to a browser so i can watch it anywhere on my network. I am looking for a solution. I have video stream working with mjpg-streamer.